# bad operand types for binary operator '*' how to covert the type to int

Tags: java

I'm having some problems with the following program.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Int x =new Int(3);
    int y= square() +twice() +once();
    System.out.println(y);
}

private int square (Int x)
{
    x= x*x;
    return x;
}

private int twice (Int x)
{
    x= 2*x;
    return x;
}

private int once (Int x)
{
    x= x;
    return x;
}
```

and the output for this program should be 45.

here is the Int class.

```
public class Int {
private int x;
public Int (int x)
{
    this.x=x;
}
```

the problem I have is in

```
  private int square (Int x)
  {
      x= x*x;
      return x;
  }
```

x=x*x gives an error of bad operand types for binary operator '*'.first type Int, Second Type Int.

I know for '*' to work it need an int type, I tried to use Integer.parseInt(x), but it says, x is not a string.

can someone help me?
what causes this problem and how to fix it.

Comment: `parseInt()` requires a String to be passed to it. You are trying to pass an `Int` object.

Comment: Also, your `Int` class is pretty useless; you could just use a primitive `int` for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple: you define an `Int` type and expect it to be implicitly convertible to a primitive `int` but this has nothing to do with what your `Int` type is expected to be in your design, it could be called `Foo` instead that `Int` but that would be the same.

If you want to be able to get the `int` value wrapped inside an `Int` instance then you must provide your own way to do it, eg:

```
class Int {
  int x;

  public int intValue() { return x; }
}
```

so that you can do:

```
Int x = new Int(3);
int square = x.intValue() * x.intValue();
```

or, to avoid breaking encapsulation:

```
class Int
{
  int x;

  public Int(int x) { this.x = x; }

  public Int square() { return new Int(x*x); }
  /* or: int square() { return x*x; }*/
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I don't want a public int intValue () in the Int class. I want to keep the private method under the main method. Is there any way to keep my Int class unchange, and make x=x*x work in the private method?

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Int` looks (very lightly) like the `Integer` wrapper. If you really need a wrapper, use the very tested Java `Integer`, otherwise, use the primitive `int`.
Remember, Java does not support operator overloading.